# Rendering does not seem to work for new post on dba.SE

Tags: bug, markdown

Is it just me, or is there a problem with the rendering of markdown?
Just posted this answer on dba.SE:

[Searching for a close numeric match on spatial coordinates](https://dba.stackexchange.com/revisions/282403/2)

Unlike with other (pre-existing) posts, rendering seems to fail.

[I see this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OcZz.png)

Comment: I see it fine, both in the post and your picture. What is the problem? Can you mark the problematic area somehow, or explain better?

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating: Glorfindel helped me to fix a markup error.

Comment: But what error? I don't see any problem.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating I've changed the link to point at the revision with the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is this block of code near the end of your post:

````
```
SELECT *, ((longitude - 9.876543210987654321) ^ 2
        + (latitude   - 1.234567890123456789) ^ 2) AS squared_dist
FROM   tbl
WHERE  ((longitude - 9.876543210987654321) ^ 2
      + (latitude  - 1.234567890123456789) ^ 2) < 0.000000001  -- or whatever
ORDER  BY point (longitude, latitude)
      <-> point '(9.876543210987654321,1.234567890123456789)'
LIMIT  10;
```pgsql
````

The ```` ```pgsql ```` is not recognized as the end of a code block; the language hint should be at the beginning instead.